# Load Database table using Ajax & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a dropdown menu like this:

```
<select name="location_" required="required" id="location_">
        <option value="Location_1">Location_1</option>
        <option value="Location_2">Location_2</option>
        <option value="Location_3">Location_3</option>
</select>
```

So what I need is that when I select one of the options in the dropdown menu load automatic a table that have reference with my selection...

For example:

I have in mySQL database:

table 1: location 1
table 2: location 2
table 3: location 3

if I select location 2 in the dropdown menu automatic I will load in Ajax the table 2 and the same for other selections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js:

```
$('#location_').on('change', function(e) {
    $.post("ajax/get-table.php", { 'option' : $(this).val() }, function(data){
        //whatever you want to do with the response from the file
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then within `ajax/get-table.php` you make the call to the database and grab whatever you need. Return it as a json encoded string (or array, depends what your needs are). and boom, you'll have the info in a JS variable called data and you can put that data where you need it to go.